# Trouble removing whitespaces from string array

Tags: arrays, kotlin, whitespace, removing-whitespace

New to asking questions here and to Kotlin so,

I'm making a simple command parser for a command line app. I handle input but splitting the string at whitespaces but it could possibly result in "empty array indexes". This is the code I currently have for trying to remove it but, the console will never print "Found Whitespace", so I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

```
var input = readLine()?.trim()?.split(" ")

        input = input?.toMutableList()
        println(input)
        if (input != null) {
            for(i in input){
                println("Checked")
                if(i == " "){
                    println("Found Whitespace")
                    if (input != null) {
                        input.removeAt(input.indexOf(i))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        println(input)
```

Here's the console for a command that repeats the first number by the second

```
repeat   5  5 // command
[repeat, , , 5, , 5]  //what the array looks like before whitespace removal
Checked
Checked
Checked
Checked
Checked
Checked
[repeat, , , 5, , 5] //what the array looks like after whitespace removal
```

Hopefully this makes sense...

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for `""` instead of `" "`? Regardless it would likely be better to remove the extra whitespace from the string itself, or even better split using regex (to include multiple spaces).

Comment: How do you want the array to look like at the end?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yes checking for "" worked and actually makes a lot of sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split the string with consecutive spaces as a delimiter, you can use a regex for that.

```kotlin
val input = readLine()
if(input != null) {
    val words = input.trim().split(Regex(" +")) // here '+' is used to capture one or more consecutive occurrences of " "
    println(words)
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/rQdii9xJ9)

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes here,

- you are iterating array using `forEach` and removing indices , this may cause `IndexOutOfBoundError` or some other some ambiguous behavior.

You can just use `filter` here,

```
val a = listOf(" " ," " ," " ," " ,"1" ,"2" ,"3")
print( a.filter{it != " "} )
```

returns

`[1, 2, 3]`

[playground](https://pl.kotl.in/D-rVm738e)

Comment: Thank you for the help! This worked well for me but I think just splitting the string with a Regex is a bit cleaner. Thank you so much